# How to get previous three months data based on one column's date data in sql?

Tags: sql

I now have one sql table which has three columns -- id, work_date, and due_date. How can I select rows if work_date is within the past three months of due_date?

It's like "due_date - 3 months < work_date < work_date".

Comment: SQL is a broad term, and the syntax varies depending on which environment you are using. Therefore, please list the dbm in question. I.e. MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle etc.

Comment: `work_date < due_date - interval '3 months'`?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, because it's an inside company database based on hive, I'm trying to contact the designer to know which environment it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-SQL you can use `dateadd` function like that:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE work_date > dateadd(day, -90, due_date) AND word_date < due_date;
```

or just

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE work_date > due_date - 90 AND work_date < due_date;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, before using dateadd or just minus, do I need to convert the column type to date type? Don't know why, but I can't successfully used the dateadd func and the minus way in my database.

Comment: I forgot to mention my data is like '2018-03-15 00:00:00'

Comment: At last, I find out that it's oracle, not sql, thanks.